# koa user application delete and update problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, koa

im trying to make function do delete a specific user by his id but the thing happpening is that it deletes all the users in the list. when i send get request with postman it returns
an empty array  what am i doing wrong? i don't have a database but i have local json file which i created and i do everything with that json
here is
user.controller.ts

```
// const events_db = ["123",112333333];
import user from "./user.json"
console.log(user)



export const getUser = (ctx: { body?: any; status: number; }) => {
  ctx.body = user;
  ctx.status = 200;
};

export const addUser = (ctx: { request: {  body?: any; }; body: string; status: number;  }) => {
  user.Users.push(ctx.request.body);
  ctx.body = "User Created!";
  ctx.status = 201;
};


export const deleteUser = ((ctx: { body: string; status: number; }) =>{
  const filtered = user.Users.filter((obj,index) => obj.id !== user.Users[index].id)
  console.log(filtered)
  user.Users = filtered
   ctx.body= "user deleted"
   ctx.status = 202
})
```

and here is user-routes.ts

```
import Router from "koa-router";
const router = new Router();
import {getUser, addUser,deleteUser} from "./controllers/user.controllers"


router.get("/user_list", getUser);
router.post("/add_user", addUser);
router.delete("/:id/delete_user", deleteUser)
// router.put("/:id/update_user" , update_user)

export default router;
```

and here is the user.json

```
{
   "Users" : [
    {
   "id":"1",
    "username" : "luka",
    "email" : "tesset@123.com",
    "phone_number": "5555555",
    "password" : "123",
    "personal_number" : "1111",
    "first_name":"lll",
    "last_name": "llll",
    "birth_date":"010101",
    "nick_name":"abbb",
    "gender_id" : "1",
    "culture_id":"2",
    "role_id":"3",
    "department_id":"5",
    "group_id": "1",
    "avatar" : ""
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "username" : "lukaa",
        "email" : "tesset@123a.com",
        "phone_number": "55552555",
        "password" : "1233",
        "personal_number" : "11111",
        "first_name":"l2ll",
        "last_name": "lll3l",
        "birth_date":"0104101",
        "nick_name":"abb5b",
        "gender_id" : "61",
        "culture_id":"211",
        "role_id":"322",
        "department_id":"335",
        "group_id": "144#",
        "avatar" : ""
    }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
const filtered = user.Users.filter((obj,index) => obj.id !== user.Users[index].id)
```

Here you are comparing the same object with itself and there of course the id is always the same so the not equal `!==` will the return NO object. You are not using the params.id from the delete route.

Modify your code to:

```
const filtered = user.Users.filter((obj) => obj.id !== ctx.params.id)
```

Code not testet but I think you get the point ...